# Nothing is rendered after navigation in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using SwitchNavigator from `React-navigation` for Authentication in `React-native` app. In the Authorized Section, I want to show a side Drawer for showing options like settings and log out. Entering into the Authorized section by clicking the button in tabs section user should be able to go to details section of an album. For that, I am using StackNavigator.

Issue:
After Authentication, Once I navigate to a section with Side Drawer in which stack navigator is present,  nothing is rendered once navigated to Authorized section. Even the Test screen is mounted(checked through componentDidMount) nothing is displayed.

```
 const Stages = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
     testStage1: { screen: TestScreen },
     testStage2: { screen: TestScreen },
     testStage3: { screen: TestScreen },
     testStage4: { screen: TestScreen },
 })
 const AuthorizedSectionRouteConf={
    navigation:{
        stages: {
            screen : Stages,
        },
        details : {
            screen: DetailsScreen,
        }
    },
    navigationOptions:{
        headerLeft:null
    }
}
const AuthorizedSectionNavigator =
 createStackNavigator(AuthorizedSectionRouteConf.navigation);
const Config = {
      navigation: {
          UnauthorizedSection: {
            screen: ({navigation}) => <LoginScreen navigate={navigation.navigate}/>,
            navigationOptions:{
                header:null,
                mode:'modal'
            }
          },
          AuthorizedSection: {
            screen:  createDrawerNavigator({
                Home:{
                    screen: ({navigation}) => <AuthorizedSectionNavigator screenProps={{drawerNavigator:navigation}} />
                    }
                })
        },
        TestSection: TestScreen
    }
}
export default AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(Config.navigation);
```

Navigation after navigation:

```
this.props.navigate('AuthorizedSection')
==> nothing is visible after this.
```

However,  If I navigate to TestScreen after Authentication which is simple text on screen
it rendered properly.

```
this.props.navigate('TestSection')
    ==> working properly
```

Comment: You have to add screen title like `Home` in navigation area, you cannot call whole object of `AuthorizedSection` in navigation

Comment: not working. Anyways I want SideDrawer in my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that there is no space for the component to render. Fixed it by setting the flex property for the parent container.